# Using IF statement in vb with database material

Tags: sql, vb.net, if-statement

So I'm trying to use an If statement based on criteria in my database and I'm not sure how I'm new to vb. The viewaccess, editaccess, and approveaccess are bits in my database.

```
 If (Session("ViewAccess") = 1) And Session("EditAccess") = 0 And (Session("ApproveAccess") = 0) Then
            btnSaveTop.Visible = False
            btnSaveBottom.Visible = False
            btnApproveTop.Visible = False
            btnApproveBottom.Visible = False
            btnRequestUnapproveTop.Visible = False
            btnRequestUnapproveBottom.Visible = False
            RequiredData.FreightWBS.ReadOnly = True
            RequiredData.GemFeeWBS.ReadOnly = True
            RequiredData.Approver.ReadOnly = True
        End If
```

Comment: "`The viewaccess, editaccess, and approveaccess are bits in my database`".  Uhm... no.  They are bits in your `Session` - unless you are, bizarrely, calling your database object `Session`.

Comment: they are bits in my database I just don't know what to put them as in vb or how to even call them

Comment: You said it is in your database; What database are you using? How are you  getting the data out of the database?

Answer (score -1):

When you get values from the database they are not anymore 1 or 0 (bit type). **They are true or false (boolean), change that.** No idea how you're filling session but it looks like an SqlDataReader if that's your case, doing that will fix your problem. (Be more explicit)